# Developing Google Authentication in Maui Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

Hello community I'm developing an application using .NET Maui blazer in which I want to integrate google authentication but unfortunately I'm unable to find any solution for this as I've tried web authenticator as per Microsoft instruction web-authenticator doesn't support windows application, the other thing is I don't want to use web API for this. does anyone know any solution do let me know.

That's what i've tried and many more from youtube and Microsoft officials:
https://auth0.com/blog/add-authentication-to-dotnet-maui-apps-with-auth0/
I'm looking for a hint or very small idea to get going?
Thanks!